# How to repeat the same md-card content when click on add button using angular2 or typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have a md-card inside which i had written the contents, when i click on add button, i must get the same md-card content just below the present md-card, and it must go on adding, how many times i click on it.

I need the same position field to come below position, when i click on add button.

HTML:

```
<md-card layout="column" class="border-top-3px col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                        <div class="clearfix col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-mini add-task" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Add" aria-label="New Task" (click)="openAdd()" style="bottom: 70%; right: 2%;">
                        <md-icon style="color:white;">add</md-icon>
                        </button>
                            <h6 class="color-primary md-headline" style="font-size:18px;">Adding</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="font-size:13px;">
                            <md-input-container>
                                <input mdInput type="text" name="workName" [(ngModel)]="workName" placeholder="Work Name" required />
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container>
                                <input mdInput type="text" name="workName" [(ngModel)]="workName" placeholder="Work Name" required />
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="font-size: 13px;
                    text-align: left;">
                            <md-input-container>
                                <input mdInput type="text" name="workName" [(ngModel)]="workName" placeholder="Work Name" required />
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container>
                                <input mdInput type="text" name="workName" [(ngModel)]="workName" placeholder="Work Name" required />
                            </md-input-container>
                    </md-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `postions array` in component.

Use that array and bind in `*ngFor`

Component:

```
export class Component {
    positions = [{ workName: '', work: ''}];
    constructor() {}
    public addPosition() {
      this.positions.push({ workName: '', work: ''});
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<md-button (click)="addPosition()" md-no-ink class="md-primary">Add new position</md-button>

    <md-card *ngFor="let pos of positions; let i = index" layout="column" class="border-top-3px col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="clearfix col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-mini add-task" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Add" aria-label="New Task" (click)="openAdd()"
          style="bottom: 70%; right: 2%;">
          <md-icon style="color:white;">add</md-icon>
        </button>
        <h6 class="color-primary md-headline" style="font-size:18px;">Adding</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="font-size:13px;">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput type="text" name="workName_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="pos.workName" placeholder="Work Name" required />
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="font-size: 13px;
                        text-align: left;">
        <md-input-container>
          <input mdInput type="text" name="work_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="pos.work" placeholder="Work" required />
        </md-input-container>
    </md-card>
```

**Check the binding of ngModel:**

```
<input mdInput type="text" name="work_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="pos.work" placeholder="Work" required />
```

**For (+) button I added a button, please check:**

```
<md-button (click)="addPosition()" md-no-ink class="md-primary">Add new position</md-button>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i will try and update you answer

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a array in the component where you store 1 element for each card, then you can just push an item on click and finally on the template you just use a ngFor to repeat the element for each item in the array.

UPDATE

take this as an example

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1 *ngFor="let el of elements">HELLO</h1>
    <button (click)="addElement()">Add element!</button>
  `
})
export class MyApp {

  constructor() {
    this.elements = new Array();
  }

  public addElement() {
    this.elements.push(1);
    console.log(this.elements);
  }
}

bootstrap(MyApp);
```

Comment: i am sorry, i am new to this, can you help me how to write in typescript

Comment: i need the template which i had pasted only to display down on click, please help

Comment: just use the code snippet that i sent to you, changing the h1 to whatever is your template

Comment: i have no contents for ng-if. can i paste the html content in code to template of your answer